# Problem switching languages [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS]

Tags: 12.04, language-support

How can i switch languages using a keyboard shortcut?
I can only switch them using mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In System Settings, Keyboard, Layout Settings, Options, you have many choices for a key combination to change layout, none being the default

[image]